# Nested `for loop` printing all objects rather than related objects

Tags: doctrine-orm, twig, symfony4

Im currently working on a forum using Symfony 4 and Doctrine.

Im having issues comprehending what to do next and need some input to find out what way i need to go forward to get the desired results.

my knowledge is limited and i have been taking a KNPU course for Symfony 4 > Doctrine, Admittedly i have skimmed a few sections of the Relations tutorials but the 'fetching relations' scenario is different to my own, the tutorial only fetches 1 object defined by the {slug}, this will help me later.

My Intent

I am trying to pull All of my Category entity and loop the names as html Headers, then within that loop want to run another loop to list topics associated with that category.
For Reference `core.html.twig` The template that holds my loops(included in my base template so it can be overwritten)

```
<div>
    <div id="forum head">
        <div id="category">
        {% for category in categories %}
            <h4>{{ category.name }}</h4>
            {% for topic in topics %}
                <h6>{{ topic.name }}</h6>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Problem

How ever i build my topics array in the controller i always get ALL topics regardless of association.

Hypothesis,
Because im calling for ALL Category Objects then i reference Category to refine topics its passing ALL Category Id's and therefore returning all Topics.

The whole Controller isnt here, but i have included the Function snippet

```
     /**
     * @Route("/forum", name="page_forum")
     */
    public function index(CategoryRepository $repository, TopicRepository $topicRepository)
    {
        $category = $repository->findBy([],['placement' => 'ASC']);
        $topic = $topicRepository->findBy(['category' => $category],['placement' => 'ASC']);

        return $this->render('forum/index.html.twig', [
            'categories' => $category,
            'topics' => $topic
        ]);
    }
```

In my profiler i see the SQL executed to get my topics

```
SELECT t0.id AS id_1, 
t0.name AS name_2, 
t0.placement AS placement_3,
t0.created_at AS created_at_4, 
t0.updated_at AS updated_at_5,
t0.category_id AS category_id_6 
FROM topic t0 
WHERE t0.category_id IN (?) ORDER BY t0.placement ASC
Parameters:
[▼
  [▼
    41
    42
    43
    44
    45
  ]
]
```

This Proves that the topic is using ALL category Id's.

Down to the brass tacks, how do i make my 'topics' loop only pull the correct topics for the category it is nested under? Custom Query(if so how, my attempt failed), a twig extension filter? or any method i have not thought of?

Any Advice on getting past this roadblock would be appreciated
If i missed anything let me know

EDIT:

My Entitys `Category` & `Topic` are related as follows (saw a similar question including these and realized its rather impotent)

Category

```
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Topic", mappedBy="category")
     */
    private $topics;
```

Topic

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="topics")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $category;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have added your getters and setters to your entities, You should be able to use them in you twig template:

```
<div id="forum head">
    <div id="category">
    {% for category in categories %}
        <h4>{{ category.name }}</h4>
        {% for topic in category.getTopics() %}
            <h6>{{ topic.name }}</h6>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

also, you don't really need to return Topic objects in your controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/forum", name="page_forum")
 */
public function index(CategoryRepository $repository, TopicRepository $topicRepository)
{
    $category = $repository->findBy([],['placement' => 'ASC']);
    //$topic = $topicRepository->findBy(['category' => $category],['placement' => 'ASC']);

    return $this->render('forum/index.html.twig', [
        'categories' => $category,
        //'topics' => $topic
    ]);
}
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31126741/6542373) may help you even more

Comment: Thanks For the help, the idea of  calling category up again had not crossed my mind. i was able use `{% for topic in category.topics %}` as twig converts the `.topics` into `.getTopics()`

Still, Thanks so much